# R function to determine if missing data is related

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a dataset with quite a bit of missing data in some columns (~20%) and am trying to figure out what proportion of these are in the same patients (ex. are the 20% of patients missing heart rate the same 20% that are missing systolic blood pressure?). The main purpose of this is to determine whether it is more common for data to be missing in patients with particular outcomes. I've tried to use the varclus package in R but I haven't been having any luck. Any suggestions and guidance is greatly appreciated, thank you! :)

Comment: You can create a missing logical  column  `df$missing <- is.na(df$col1) | is.na(df$col2) | is.na(df$col3)` then starts from here to do whathever analysis you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse workflow to visualize missingness across your dataset:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

starwars %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), is.na)) %>% 
  arrange(across(everything())) %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(!row, names_to = "column", values_to = "missing") %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_tile(aes(row, column, fill = missing))
```

[image]

For starters, it looks like the same rows tend to be missing `species`, `sex`, and `gender`. To confirm, we can do:

```r
starwars %>% 
  count(across(c(species, sex, gender), is.na))

#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   species sex   gender     n
#>   <lgl>   <lgl> <lgl>  <int>
#> 1 FALSE   FALSE FALSE     83
#> 2 TRUE    TRUE  TRUE       4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

This confirms that in all cases where `species`, `sex`, and `gender` are missing, the other two are missing as well.

PS - the [mice](https://amices.org/mice/) package has more tools for exploring missing data.

Comment: Thanks! Quick follow up, how would I be able to add a condition/argument to the count(across(c(species, sex, gender), is.na)) line? For example, for entries missing species and gender, how would I be able to find out the proportion of those who are sex==male?

Comment: To cross the missing counts with other variables, you can add them to `count()` outside of the `across()` call. So for example, `count(across(c(species, sex, gender), is.na), sex)`.

Answer (score 1):

The **naniar** R package for missing data visualization, offers multiple easy to call missing data plotting functions - very practical to explore your missing data. (here is a link to the package documentation to see, what plots are available [naniar plot gallery](https://naniar.njtierney.com/articles/naniar-visualisation.html)).

For example these two plots could really help you:

**1. Missingness across factors**

```
gg_miss_fct(x = riskfactors, fct = marital)
```

[image]

**2. Combinations of missingness across cases**

Upset plot for combinations of missingness across cases (see combinations of missingness and intersections of missingness amongst variables).

```
gg_miss_upset(riskfactors)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The other options here are good, but a couple additional options are missingness maps and missingness matrices from the mice and Amelia packages. I demonstrate below on the `airquality` dataset in R.

```
#### Load Libraries ####
library(mice)
library(Amelia)

#### Missingness Map ####
missmap(airquality)

#### Missingness Matrix ####
md.pattern(airquality)
```

The missingness map looks like this, where the horizontal sweeps in white indicate some relationship between missing values. You can see here that ozone and solar radiation have some related missingness at times, but it is fairly minor:

[image]

The matrix looks like this, which shows by row and by column missingness across variables. For example, Row 1 is completely observed (no missing data) with 111 values. Row 2 has 35 counts of one missingness pattern (ozone):

[image]